# How to position matplotlib's Button without moving the title and labels as well

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, mplcursors

I'm a begginner at matplotlib/Python and I am building an animated scatter plot. I want to place a button below the plot so the user can start/pause/resume the animation. This is the plot (I know it's a mess, still working on it):
[image]

As a start I tried to add a button named Play to replay the animation after its first automatic execution, but I'm having trouble understanding how positioning it below the plot works, for it is "dragging" everything with it (the title, xlabel, ylabel and so on):
[image]

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import mplcursors
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

df = pd.read_excel('nations2.xls')
df.head()

uniqueYears = df['Ano'].unique()

font = {'family': 'sans-serif',
    'color':  'black',
    'weight': 'normal',
    'size': 16,
    }  

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def animate(frames):   
    ax.clear()    
    data = df[df['Ano'] == uniqueYears[frames]]
    ax.scatter(y = data['ExpecVida'],
    x = data['PIBperCapita'],
    s = data['PopX1000']/40000,
    c = data['Regiao'].astype('category').cat.codes,
    cmap = cm.viridis,
    edgecolors = 'none',
    alpha = 0.5)

    ax.set_xlim([0,50000], auto=True)
    ax.set_ylim([0,100], auto=True)

    plt.title('Wealth and Health of Nations', fontsize=18)
    plt.xlabel('GDP per Capita ($)', fontsize=14)
    plt.ylabel('Life Expectancy (years)', fontsize=14)
    plt.grid(color = '#A9A9A9')
    plt.text(2, 0.65, uniqueYears[frames], fontdict=font)

    for i, txt in enumerate(data['Pais']):
        ax.annotate(txt, (data['PIBperCapita'].iat[i], data['ExpecVida'].iat[i]), fontsize = 6)


anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(uniqueYears),interval = 200, repeat=False)

class Index(object):
ind = 0

def play(self, event):
    FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(uniqueYears),interval = 200, repeat=False)

callback = Index()
axplay = plt.axes([0.81, 0.05, 0.1, 0.075])
bplay = Button(axplay, 'Play')
bplay.on_clicked(callback.play)
```

Comment: The button itself is positionned correctly. Everything else is probably incorrectly placed, but since you don't show it here, it's hard to tell what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I omitted what I thought was irrelevant to the question, but I've just updated it with the rest of the code.

Comment: Ah ok; don't use pyplot when working with several axes. Replace `plt.title("...")` by `ax.set_title("...")` etc.